# The HikariPC connection pooling not share connection pool between clients?

Tags: java, oracle

I am using HikariPC API connection pooling with JDBC in my desktop application. The connection pooling is establish perfectly with maximum pooling size 10 and 10 session is created in oracle database. The problem is that when every individual client run the application 10 session created in database and it's not use the shared connection pooling which is already created. instead it's create for every new connected client 10 session in database.
Here is my code:

```
 public class ConnectionPool {

private static Properties properties = null;
private static HikariDataSource dataSource;

static {
    try {
        dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

        dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//128.1.10.150:1521/orcl");
        dataSource.setUsername("scott");
        dataSource.setPassword("faizi");

        dataSource.setMinimumIdle(100);
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(10);//The maximum number of connections, idle or busy, that can be present in the pool.
        dataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
        dataSource.setLoginTimeout(3);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionPool.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

}
```

And when I call the connection class :

```
public void addCountryToObservableList() {
    String sql = "select * from country";
    try (Connection conn =ConnectionPool.getDataSource().getConnecton();
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql); ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            countries.add(new Country(rs.getInt("code"), rs.getString("country")));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ShowErroMessage(ex, "addCountryToObservableList() methods");
    }
 }
```

I thing connection pooling work like share printer or DHCP which share between clients.
I put connection pooling diagram may be help.[image]

Comment: Connection pool doesn’t magically share connections between clients. It shares connections _within the application_.

Comment: sorry I am confuse if connection pooling shares connections within the application like application doing (update, delete, insert) which require connection opening and close for every query and this connection pooling help to reuse the connection and this connection pooling is for only one client which running the application for (insertion, deletion, updating ).

Answer (score 1):

Connection pool is a singleton (usually, but does not have to be) in the scope of the application. If you open your application N times, you will end up with N connection pools. There is not magic sharing of internal resources between application instances. If you need such sharing, you have to implement it (or find library that does that for you)

The reason for collection pooling is that connection establishment is expensive, so instead of creating/closing new connecion every time you need one, connectin pool "lends" you already alive connection making whole processing faster. But that happens only within the application and worldwide

Comment: if for every client connection pooling is established so the database hung and the performance slow down.

Comment: Correct, but that does not matter if you use connection pooling or not. In your case, removing connection pooling will slow down you client applications a littlebit, but the same problem will happen when you will get x10 users. In most cases you dont connection to the database directly but through yor application API which is on server side. Then only server establishes connection to the DB - and the problem is gone. This is actually how you canestablish "global pooling".

Comment: If you dont use multithreading and you do not do to more than 1 db operation at the time, either emove CP or set it to max 1 connection with some idle time.

Comment: @Antoniosss removing the pool is a bad idea. Things like idle testing, refreshing connections, managing resources and preventing/detecting leaks - these are not trivial concerns. Using raw JDBC is a bad idea.

Comment: Is there any solution for connection pooling which share between clients form one source  instead of creating connection pool for every individual client?

Comment: Yest there is and it is server side application processing.